# Guava BloomFilters: is there a limit for the number of expected insertions?

Tags: guava, bloom-filter

In this rather old thread here https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1067, it is implied that the maximum number of expected insertions has to be smaller than Integer.MAX_VALUE. I expect to have approximately 20 billion insertions. Are the Guava BloomFilters reliable in this case?

Comment: Guava migrated to GitHub recently, now the issue is here: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1067.

Answer (score 3):

So the answer is yes, the limit is Integer.MAX_VALUE. The proposed solution is to use a fixed pool of bloom filters and first hash the item to select one of these bloom filters.

**EDIT**

So this has been recently fixed by the guava team starting with the 19.0-SNAPSHOT version. The limit is now Long.MAX_VALUE, although big expected insertions values in combination with small fpp values easily lead the VM to OOM errors.